# Tuples, checking for a letter in a string

Tags: python, tuples

I have this code:

```
prefixes = "JKLMNOPQ" 
suffix = "ack" 

for letter in prefixes: 
    if letter in ("O", "Q"):
        print letter + "u" + suffix
    else:
        print letter + suffix
```

It works fine but I have problem understanding one thing. I assume that:

```
if letter in ("O", "Q"):
```

creates new tuple with 2 letters: O and Q and checks if value letter is present.

What I'm unsure about is why this won't work correctly:

```
if letter == "O" or "Q":
```

This code will add "u" to all prefixes and not just those with "O" and "Q".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All these do the same thing:

```
if letter == "O" or letter == "Q":
if letter in ("O", "Q"):
if letter in "OQ":
```

Your line `if letter == "O" or "Q":` is evaluated like `if (letter == "O") or "Q":`, and `"Q"` evaluates to `True`, so this expression always returns `True`.

Comment: You missed one "=" in your first example. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Equality comparison takes precedence over "or" operator: http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#summary

`if letter == "O" or "Q":`

succeeds if 1) letter is "O" or 2) "Q"

Since "Q" evaluates to True, this if statement always succeeds.

Answer (score 1):

```
if letter == "O" or "Q":
```

This can be rewritten to:

```
if (letter == "O") or ("Q"):
```

And the last part, a string that is not empty, always evaluates to `True`, thus your whole expression is `True`.

So you have write it like this:

```
if letter == "O" or letter == "Q":
```

Or use your tuple code (better).

Comment: I find it to be much more readable and concise, nothing more.

Answer (score 1):

The issue lies here:

```
if letter == "O" or "Q":
```

It should be:

```
if letter == "O" or letter == "Q":
```

The reason you were getting "u" added to all prefixes was because "Q" is always true.

Answer (score 1):

It's worth noting that even if the precedence were different, it wouldn't work:

```
if letter == ("O" or "Q"):
```

This is no good, since `"O"` is true-ish*, so `"O" or "Q"` is "O", so we would just compare `letter` to `"O"` and ignore `"Q"` completely.

In English, we think of `"O" or "Q"` as an abstract concept that is non-deterministically either `"O"` or `"Q"` according to whatever the logic requires. Computers, however, deal in deterministic quantities. The closest we can get to the English phrasing `Is the letter "O" or "Q"?` (and more precise, while we're at it :) ) is `Is the letter one of the following: "O", "Q"?` which we can formalize a bit as `Is the letter in the following set: {"O", "Q"}?`

Python allows us to construct sets easily (with the `set`) keyword, but we must still be explicit about the fact that we are checking if `letter` is `in` this set (i.e., we test for **set membership**, not equality). Fortunately, we don't strictly require a set to check for membership. (If we had a huge number of elements to test, and we only needed to construct the set once but had many letters to test, then we might save time overall by formally creating a `set`, since they're optimized for the membership test; with a `tuple` like `("O", "Q")`, Python needs to check each element one at a time. But here, the `tuple` works just fine.)

In short: you fix the problem the way the others said, but their explanation of the problem ought to leave you asking more questions (which I hope I answered here).